# ValidationError with Datatime field in Django

Tags: python, django

I am working with the `date picker` of `Tempus Dominus Bootstrap 4` in my Django project. template's date-picker link: [Doc](https://getdatepicker.com/5-4/Usage/)

in my `models.py`:

```
class Industry(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    mycustomdate = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

in my `template`:

```
<form method="post" class="row m-0">
  {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Industry Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Type industry name">
    </div>
    <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1" data-target-input="nearest">
      <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" name="mycustomdate" data-target="#datetimepicker1"/>
      <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#datetimepicker1" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
        <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <a href="#" class="ml-auto mr-3 my-4"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button></a>
</form>

<script>
  $(function () {
    $("#datetimepicker1").datetimepicker();
  });
</script>
```

in my `views.py`:

```
if request.method == "POST":
  this_mycustomdate = request.POST['mycustomdate']

  print(this_mycustomdate)

  Industry_obj = Industry.objects.create(name=this_name, mycustomdate = this_mycustomdate)
  Industry_obj.save()
```

But it says error like:

```
ValidationError at /industrySignup/
['“03/04/2021 5:06 PM” value has an invalid format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format.']
```

with the line:

```
Industry_obj = Industry.objects.create(name=this_name, mycustomdate = this_mycustomdate)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What is `this_mycustomdate`? You haven't shown it's code. Also where do these `”` special quotes come from?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat it has come from the `form` of the template by post method. I just add the `template` also, please check that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you appear to have some special quote characters around your date string, remove them:

```
this_mycustomdate = this_mycustomdate.strip('“”') # Note these are not the normal double quotes
```

Next convert your string into a datetime instance:

```
from datetime import datetime

this_mycustomdate = datetime.strptime(this_mycustomdate, "%d/%m/%Y %I:%M %p") # I have considered the format of the date as DD/MM/YYYY
```

After this you should be good to go.

Comment: thanks a lot, now it is working perfectly!