# time data '03/16/2021 5:06 PM' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y %I:%M %p'

Tags: python, django

I have a variable in my `Django` project named `this_rmg_date`.

Now I am trying to reformat it (for saving it in my database's `DateTimeField`)

```
print(this_rmg_date)
this_rmg_date = datetime.strptime(this_rmg_date, "%d/%m/%Y %I:%M %p")
```

Here the `print(this_rmg_date)` print the value in console, and it is: `03/16/2021 5:06 PM`

but an error occers with the next line, it says:

```
ValueError at /input_industryinfo/
time data '03/16/2021 5:06 PM' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y %I:%M %p'
```

Yesterday, I did almost the same kind of code and that was working perfectly, other parts of my code are like this: [stackOverflow-link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65941808/validationerror-with-datatime-field-in-django).

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

16 is an invalid month. Your input is arriving in mm/dd/YYYY format. Try this:

```
this_rmg_date = '03/16/2021 5:06 PM'
this_rmg_date = datetime.strptime(this_rmg_date, "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p")
>>> this_rmg_date
datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 16, 17, 6)
```

You could also use the third party module [`dateutil`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)'s parser, which can handle this:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
>>> parse('03/16/2021 5:06 PM')
datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 16, 17, 6)
>>> parse('16/03/2021 5:06 PM')
datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 16, 17, 6)
```

But it can only do so much without help:

```
>>> parse('04/03/2021 5:06 PM')
datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 3, 17, 6)
>>> parse('04/03/2021 5:06 PM', dayfirst=True)
datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 4, 17, 6)
```